# Closing a Out of Browser application in silverlight from the code

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

How do I close an out of the browser application in silverlight programatically. I want to bring in the same functionality as the control box close, from the code based on some condition. How do I acheive it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As simple as that :)

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

Comment: note that this requires the application to be trusted